# How to override the type on a render prop?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I'm using [react-hook-form](https://www.react-hook-form.com) and I made a HOC to wrap the react-hook-form Controller component.

Here's a simplified version of the component:

```
const ControllerInput: React.FC<ControllerInputProps> = ({
  control,
  name,
  label
}: ControllerInputProps) => (
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    render={({
      field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
      fieldState: { invalid, isTouched },
    }) => (
      <IonInput
        className={setFormControllerImportClass(invalid, isTouched)}
        label={label}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onIonBlur={onBlur}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

I'm using the [type-coverage](https://github.com/plantain-00/type-coverage) package to ensure I've typed everything.

**type-coverage** identifies the type of `value` in `field: { onChange, onBlur, value }` as `any`, so I want to change it to `unknown`.  However, `field: { onChange, onBlur, value }` is, according to the react-hook-form docs, a [render prop](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), and I don't understand how to override the type from `any` to `unknown`.  I tried creating my own interface and using `: MyInterface` as well as `as MyInterface`, but I couldn't get the syntax right.

How can I change an `any` type in a third-party package (in this case, react-hook-form) to `unknown`?

Comment: Can you show the code for `<Controller />` component?

Comment: `<Controller />` is a [react-hook-form component](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/).

Comment: What is the version of `react-hook-form` and `typescript` you are using?

Comment: Typescript 5.1.6 and react-hook-form 7.45.4.